# writing a query on connected tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

I Have 3 Tables with foreign keys to each other. I want to write a SQL Server Stored Procedure to select records from one of them.

1. `msUser` : `UserId` - (Primary key), `fkRoleId` - (foreign key to msRole)
2. `msRole` : `RoleId` - (Primary key), `fkrUserId` - (foreign key to msUser)
3. `tblUserRole` : `UserRoleId` (Primary key), `fkUrRoleId` - (foreign key to msRole)

How to get particular user's details from all these three tables in SQL server 2008?

### my attempt:

```
select*from msuser
left join tblUserRole on urUserId = UserId
left join msRole on RoleId = UrRoleId
where userId = 1
```

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: Which table? Which parameter(s)? These details should be in your question..

Comment: hey @W3AVE, those details are there in my question by the way

Comment: And does your attempt fail? It looks correct

Comment: Is it me, or are table 1 and table 2 storing the same information?

Comment: asking of ralternate way, that is it!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your query is the way you want it. Try this for your stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.yourProc(@userID INT)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM msUser
    LEFT JOIN tblUserRole   ON tblUserRole.urUserId = msUser.UserId
    LEFT JOIN msRole        ON msRole.RoleId = tblUserRole.fkUrRoleId
    WHERE msUser.UserId = @userID
END
GO
```

Here's how to use your stored procedure.

```
EXEC dbo.yourProc @userID = 1;
```

Comment: @stephen, understand the question first! he needs an alternate way to get same result other than `left join`

Comment: He says he needs a stored procedure to return information about a specific UserID with his joins. I did that for him. I don't know what your saying.